# sql dynamic func - how to make it work?

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

im working on SQL 2008
im doing an SP 
and it should look like:
I have input parameter, @T Nvarchar(255)
for example it gets 4 chars: 'a,b,c,d'
i need to count the times that the chars appears in the same word
BUT with diffrent combinations:

```
Count (a)
Count (b)
Count (c)
Count (d)
Count (a+b)
Count (a+c)
Count (a+d)
Count (b+c)
Count (b+d)
Count (a+b+c+d) --means a+b+c in the same word
Count (b+c+d)
Count (c+d)
```

it have to be Dynamic because a dont know the input.
i could solve it but i need help on, how do i make all possible combinations dynamic? the input can be 10 chars long.
may be there are any method or something?
thanks for any help!

Comment: What's the desired result?

Comment: it should be like:
Combinations     amount
       a                      4    
       b                      9 
      a+b                   7
     a+b+c                6
      
etc.....

Comment: Still not clear, can you include some sample data and expected result? Kindly include them in the question.

Comment: OK:
i get an input of :'a,d,g,j'
i have a file with a short story,
i need the combinations:
in how many words i have the letter 'a+d'
in how many words i have the letter 'a+g'
in how many words i have the letter 'a + j'
'a+d+g', 'a+d+g+j' ETC....

Comment: i just cannot understand - how do i make the combinations 
that im looking for, like... if i want to put the combinations 'a+d'
into a temp table and then compare, how do i pul out 'a+d'? 
is it better now?
thank you very much.

Comment: @Michaelmeshaev, do you know how to get all letter counts separately and stuck with generating all subsets?

Comment: YES!
any idea how to make the combinations???

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
DECLARE @Words TABLE (Word VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY)
INSERT INTO @Words (Word) VALUES ('Adam'), ('John'), ('Alex'), ('Bob'), ('Barbara'),('Cabral')

DECLARE @Letters VARCHAR(10)
SET @Letters='ABCD'

DECLARE @Numbers TABLE(N INT PRIMARY KEY)
INSERT INTO @Numbers (N) VALUES (1)
WHILE @@ROWCOUNT<512
INSERT INTO @Numbers (N)
SELECT N+(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @Numbers) FROM @Numbers

DECLARE @Combinations TABLE (N INT PRIMARY KEY, SelectedLetters VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @Combinations (N, SelectedLetters)
SELECT *, (
    SELECT SUBSTRING(@Letters,N2.N,1) AS '*'
    FROM @Numbers N2
    WHERE N2.N<=LEN(@Letters)
    AND N1.N & POWER(2,N2.N-1)<>0
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
).value('.','varchar(10)') AS SelectedLetters
FROM @Numbers N1
WHERE N1.N<POWER(2,LEN(@Letters))
ORDER BY 1,2

DECLARE @AllCounts TABLE (
    Word VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    N INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Word,N),
    SelectedLetters VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    Cnt INT NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO @AllCounts
SELECT W.Word, C.N, C.SelectedLetters, X.Cnt
FROM @Words W
CROSS JOIN @Combinations C
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS Cnt
    FROM @Numbers N
    WHERE SUBSTRING(W.Word,N,1) LIKE '%['+c.SelectedLetters+']%'
) X
WHERE X.Cnt>0
ORDER BY 1,2

SELECT * FROM @AllCounts A1 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM @AllCounts A2
    WHERE A1.Word=A2.Word
    AND A1.N<>A2.N
    AND A1.N | A2.N = A1.N
    AND A1.Cnt=A2.Cnt
)
```

The @Combinations table stores all possible letter combinations. 
We compute the counts for each word into the @AllCounts table. 
At the end, we show only the relevant counts.